# Trying to rewrite URLs for wordpress / nginx / WPML install

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, wpml

I have some wordpress experience, but it's my first time using Nginx. I have a WordPress installation running on Nginx. I added WPML (multi-language plugin) https://wpml.org/

The current URL structure is https://www.maindomain.com/blog/es/.... & https://www.maindomain.com/blog/en/.... etc. Everything works fine.

**I'm looking for a way to rewrite the URLs in ninginx conf** for the whole set-up to work with: https://www.maindomain/es/blog/.... instead of https://www.maindomain.com/blog/es/ and so on.

I tried several things and eventually i got stuck on:

```
rewrite ^/blog/en/(\w+\.?.*)$ /en/blog/$1 last;
```

which gives a 404 error on both URLs.

Any ideas on how to do this? Or is there a better way of doing this other than with rewrites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...is there a better way of doing this

Possibly, yes. You can install WordPress in a root directory instead of a subdirectory (`/blog`) or [point the domain to the subdirectory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change). This will give you URLs like `maindomain.com`

You can then set the Language URL setting in WPML to "Different languages in directories". This will give you URLs like `maindomain.com/es/`. Finally, you can create a page with the `blog` slug in WordPress (you should be able to set the same slug for the translation) and it will be accessible at `maindomain.com/blog` or `maindomain.com/es/blog`.